# How to get images from Visual Studio Image Library in other dimensions?

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface, dpi

I would like to use icons in my program on some buttons to save space and be more clear. I was under the impression that the Visual Studio Image Library is meant for this. However, Visual Studio 2019 Image Library only includes 16x16 images, while I also want 20x20, 24x24 and 28x28 (and maybe more), for different dpi/scale settings. Can I create these somehow? Or does Visual Studio not support dpi-aware applications with its Image Library?
I tried exporting the 16x16 svg as a 20x20 png, both with and without upscaling it first, but both resulted in a blurry image.

Comment: I've given up on figuring out how I am supposed to do this. I now make them myself, using the larger sizes that came with the 2015 Image Library, downscaling them, and manually editing them to make them less blurry.

Comment: From the Visual Studio documentation: "Icons produced by the image service automatically generate the XAML format for HDPI support." So it sounds like it should be possible. I can't find anything about it, though, in the docs or on Stack Overflow.